# Ubuntu 13.10 x64, hybrid graphics card, can not resume after suspend

Tags: nvidia, hybrid-graphics

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 x64, my hybrid graphics card is Intel HD Graphics 4600 and Nvidia Geforce 740m.
I installed Nvidia driver follow [this article](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/08/using-nvidia-graphics-drivers-with.html). My question is my laptop can not resume from suspend,  see the pic:

[image]

After I suspend laptop and try to resume, it just shows like this. How can I fix this?

Comment: You got a bug in your hands, report it to launchpad.

Comment: I don't know how to report it, if you know how to do it, please tell me or you can do that too

Comment: There's a link in the message below where it says "reported on Launchpad"

Answer (score 1):

I think that it might be breaking unity, I would recommend you to install Ubuntu Gnome 13.10 and install the drivers the same way:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-319 nvidia-settings-319 nvidia-prime
```

Hope they don't break your GUI and that you can suspend your computer, it is not a direct solution for your problem but it is an alternative if no one can solve your problem.

Hope it helps.

```
sudo apt-get -f update  
sudo apt-get -f upgrade  
sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks, @Brask I am too used to unity to move to gnome, actually I tried gnome before, but move back to unity in the end.

Comment: Try the last 3 command on the terminal to see if you have problems with packages hope it works @William thank you for your answer.

Comment: Thanks @Brask, tried those three commands, no package installed.